# DNS problems with local hosts especially with Iphone/Ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, dns, dyndns, local-network

I have some problems communicating with different devices each other in my local network. I suggest some DNS problems or incorrect DNS settings

First of all, a short overview of my devices:

- **Router**: Speedport W 921V (latest Firmware 1.22.) using also dyndns for remote operation
- File-/Web-**Server**: Debian Squeeze running samba and apache
- Client1: **Computer** using Win 7 Pro
- Client2: Iphone/**Ipad**

Internet works fine on all devices! All clients have set the DNS to the IP of my router. The router also has the settings for port forwarding from port 80 to port 80 of my Webserver as well for port 8080. To access to my Webserver outside my local networks also works fine, but....

*Problem 1) Resolving public dyndns-address*

When I ping my public address *mysubdomain.dyndns-home.com* inside my local network, the IP will be resolved correctly without any timeout problems on all devices, but when I use my public address in a browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE) there is a timeout error message or server down message. This is the same behavior on all devices. So why can I not use my public address in my local network? To change that, what do I have to change?

*Problem 2) Resolving local devices on Iphone/Ipad*

Because I can not use my public address in my local network I want to communicate by my local device names. So all my devices are registered by their mac-address in the router. When I log into my router I can see all devices and their IP-addresses which are currently running. So if the router is the DNS for my clients, the router should resolve the local device names. That works so far for the Computers running Windows or Linux. But on my Iphone or Ipad the names will not be resolved. I also tried to refresh the lease or to forget the network and reconnect again, but still I can not communicate with my Iphone/Ipad and my other devices. So what can I do to resolve the names on my Iphone/Ipad?

Thanks for your help

Comment: iphone just aren't good with networks :(

You should try using something like websockets/HTTP that uses an ID broadcasting mechanism. You are gonna have problems for days if you rely on DNS lookups on routers. If its non-production though then it probs doesn't matter :)

Comment: does the Speedport W 921V support that websockets/HTTP?

Comment: Can't say i Have memorised the specs on that one lol

Comment: Did you ever get problem 2 resolved?

Answer (score 0):

1) Because you are in your local network you have to use private ip (you can see private ip using ipconfig on windows or ifconfig command line on linux). The public ip is for all others computers on the network. If you want test that the server works correctly you can use a proxy (like www.anonymouse.org)

Comment: But why do I not get redirected to my server. Even pinging is successful.

Comment: pinging is not the same as domain name resolution.